# Unzip file from disk and read data from it on node.js

Tags: node.js, gzip, unzip, fs

I need read unzipped file to string. I added these lines.

```
fs.readFile("report.gz", function(err, data) {
    zlib.gunzip(data, function(err, dezipped) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('length of data = ' + data.length);
        console.log('length of dezipped =' + dezipped.length);
        console.log(dezipped.toString("utf-8"));
      }
    });
  });
```

As a result I have only first line from my file (in dezipped variable), how can I read all lines ?

In console I see

```
length of data = 88875 (~ 85 Kb)
Length of dezipped = 528 (bytes)
```

I can conclude that dezipped are alredy cutted data.

Comment: `zlib.gunzip()` decompresses the entire file, not just the first line. Are you sure the file is properly UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: @robertklep I updated my question. Length of dezipped is slow (if compare with total length of zipped file) and dezipped data are alredy cutted (before using toString("utf-8")).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the case in your situation, but I can reproduce something similar by combining multiple gzip blocks into one file (which is perfectly valid AFAIK):

```
$ { echo ONE | gzip; echo TWO | gzip } > output.gz
$ gzcat output.gz
ONE
TWO
```

`zlib` will only extract the first block:

```
$ node app.js
length of data = 48
length of dezipped =4
ONE
```

I found that [`zlibjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zlibjs) will handle these files properly, though:

```
$ node app.js
length of data = 48
length of dezipped =8
ONE
TWO
```

It's a drop-in replacement, so this is all you need to do for your code to work:

```
var zlib = require('zlibjs');
```

Since it's pure JS, it will probably not be as fast, though.

Comment: Your code work, thank you. I prefer use internal (zlib) instead of external libraries (zlibjs), but now I will use your variant. Maybe in future anybody suggest how do it with zlib.

Comment: @yAnTar there is a (fixed) issue about this behaviour [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6032), but the test cases fail with the latest versions Node.js and iojs.